# Having trouble with wrapfigure including tikzpicture through a text

Tags: tikz-pgf, wrapfigure

I am sorting kind of economic definitions as you see (it is Persian). There is a picture which I made it by tikz package in an elementary way. I am going to use wrapfigure just to make a text good looking. Here is the codes:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,12pt]{book}‎ ‎
\usepackage[a]{esvect}
‎‎\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} ‎‎
‎\usepackage{pgf,tikz}‎
\usepackage{pgfplots}‎
‎\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}‎‎‎‎
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}‎
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}‎
‎\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}‎
‎\usetikzlibrary{intersections}‎ ‎    
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit}‎      
‎\usetikzlibrary{shadows,calc,matrix}‎
‎\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}‎
‎\usepackage{pgffor}‎
‎\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}‎ 
‎\usepackage{mathrsfs,mathtools}‎‎
‎‎‎‎‎‎‎\usepackage{libertine}‎
‎\usepackage{graphicx,color}‎
‎\usepackage{diagbox}‎
‎\usepackage{dsfont}‎
‎\usepackage{subcaption}‎
‎\usepackage{fontenc}‎
‎\usepackage{mathptmx}‎    
\usepackage{float}‎ ‎ 
\usepackage{geometry}‎  ‎
\geometry{text={7in,9.5in},headheight=15pt}‎
‎\geometry{left=40.5mm,right=44.5mm,top=61mm,bottom=51mm}‎ ‎
 \usepackage[all]{xy}‎  
  \usepackage{xtab}‎
 ‎\usepackage{tabto}‎ ‎     
 \usepackage{array}‎
 ‎\usepackage{booktabs}‎
 ‎\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}‎
  ‎\usepackage[computeautoilg=off]{xepersian}‎
  ‎\settextfont[Scale=1.1]{XB Niloofar}‎
  ‎\setdigitfont[Scale=1.3]{XB Niloofar}‎     
  \setlatintextfont[Scale=1.2]{Times New Roman}‎ 
  ‎\begin{document}‎      
  \subsection{‎‏‎‏‏‏سود کل}‎‎‎‎

 ‎‎‏بنابه تعریف ‏‎‎$‎P(x)=TR(x)-TC(x)‎$‎ که در آن ‎‎$‎P(x‎‏)$‎ سود کل حاصل از فروش ‎‎$‎x‎$‎‏ عدد از کالایی مشخص است. اگر دو تابع درآمد کل و هزینه کل توابعی مشتق پذیر باشند آنگاه مقدار ‎‎$‎x=a‎‎‎$‎‎‎‎‏، سود کل را ماکزیمم می کند ‎‏بشرطی که‏  اولاً ‎‎‎$‎‎$‎‎P'(a‎)=‎MR(a)-MC(a)=‎0‎‎$‎‎$‎‎‏ و ثانیاً ‎‎$‎P'(x)‎$‎‏ در اطراف $‎x=a‎$ ‎‎ از مثبت به منفی تغییر علامت دهد.‎\footnote{این تغییر علامت را می توان برای یک دسته خاص از توابع با  این بیان جابجا کرد: اگر‏ علاوه بر‎ وجود ‎‎$‎P''(‎a‎)‎$‏، ‎‎‎‎$‎P''(a)<0‎$‎‏ آنگاه ‎‎$‎x=a‎$‎‏ ماکزیمم تابع سود را نتیجه می دهد.} ‎‎‎
 ‏ ‎‏‎
 ‎\begin{wrapfigure}{l} {0.5\textwidth}‎‎
 ‎‎‎\begin{figure}‎‎‎‎‎‎[H]
‎\begin{tikzpicture}‎[>=stealth,scale=0.8‎]
\begin{axis}[axis lines = middle‎, ‎smooth‎, ‎xlabel=$Q‎$,ylabel=$P$,‎xmax=4,ymax=2,ymin=-2.08,xmin=0,x=1cm/0.45,y=1cm/0.5,xticklabels={,,},yticklabels={,,}]‎
‎\addplot [‎thick‎, line width=2pt, ‎black‎,domain=1:3,samples=70,smooth,name path=A] {0.5*x‎‎‎‎‎‎};‎‎‎
‎\addplot [‎thick‎, line width=2pt, ‎black‎,domain=1:3,samples=70,smooth,name path=A] {-0.5*x+2‎‎‎‎‎‎};‎‎‎‎
‎\addplot [‎thick‎, line width=2pt, ‎black‎,domain=0:3.5,samples=70,smooth,name path=A] {-(x-2)^2-1‎‎‎‎‎‎};‎‎‎
‎‎\draw [->, ‎‎‎‎thin‎,line width=0.5‎pt ] (0,-2)‎ -- (4,-2);‎‎
‎‎\draw [ ‎‎‎‎thin‎,line width=0.5‎pt, dashed ] (2,0)‎ -- (2,1);‎‎‎‎
‎‎\draw [ ‎‎‎‎thin‎,line width=0.5‎pt, dashed ] (0,1)‎ -- (2,1);‎‎‎‎
‎‎\draw [ ‎‎‎‎thin‎,line width=0.5‎pt, dashed ] (2,-2)‎ -- (2,-1);‎‎‎‎
‎\filldraw[black] (2,1) circle (2.5pt);‎‎‎‎
‎\filldraw[black] (2,-1) circle (2.5pt);‎‎‎‎
‎\end{axis}‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
‎‎\pgftext[base,x=8.5cm,y=0.4cm,rotate=0] {$Q‎‎$};‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
‎‎\pgftext[base,x=4.45cm,y=1.3cm,rotate=0] {\small{$MR=MC‎‎$}};‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
‎‎\pgftext[base,x=3.5cm,y=0.6cm,rotate=0] {\scriptsize{$MR>MC‎‎$}};‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
‎‎\pgftext[base,x=5.4cm,y=0.6cm,rotate=0] {\scriptsize{$MR<MC‎‎$}};‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
‎‎\pgftext[base,x=7cm,y=1.3cm,rotate=0] {\scriptsize{$\text{‏تابع سود کل}‎‎$}};‎‎‎‎‎‎
‎‎\pgftext[base,x=7cm,y=5.2cm,rotate=0] {\scriptsize{$MR‎‎$}};‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
‎‎\pgftext[base,x=1.9cm,y=5.2cm,rotate=0] {\scriptsize{$‎MC‎‎‎$}};‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
‎‎\pgftext[base,x=-0.2cm,y=6.2cm,rotate=0] {$q_0‎‎$};‎‎‎‎‎‎
‎‎\pgftext[base,x=4.52cm,y=3.8cm,rotate=0] {$p_0‎‎$};‎‎‎‎‎‎
‎\end{tikzpicture}‎‎‎‎
‎\end{figure}‏‎‎
\end{wrapfigure}
برای توجیه این مطلب به شکل زیر توجه کنید:رای توجیه این مطلب به شکل زیر توجه کنید:رای توجیه این مطلب به شکل زیر توجه کنید:رای توجیه این مطلب به شکل زیر توجه کنید:رای توجیه این مطلب به شکل زیر توجه کنید:رای توجیه این مطلب به شکل زیر توجه کنید:رای توجیه این مطلب به شکل زیر توجه کنید:رای توجیه این مطلب به شکل زیر توجه کنید:رای توجیه این مطلب به شکل زیر توجه کنید:رای توجیه این مطلب به شکل زیر توجه کنید:رای توجیه این مطلب به شکل زیر توجه کنید:

‎\end{document}‎
```

---

But, I am failed:
[image]

Where should I change to get a reasonable output. I am using `Xepersian`. Thanks for your time!

Comment: unreleated but don't use inputenc with xetex (it does nothing except give a warning that it should not be used)

Comment: you dhould never place a `figure` environment inside `wrapfigure` use one or the other, not both.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks God we have you here. I got the right way. Thanks. Many thanks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Should I delete the question?

Comment: up to you, if you think it will help others, you could post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I post this short answer shaped just to point what @David Carlisle nicely noted above. Indeed, I needed to make `wrapfigure` environment out of `figure` space. That is the straightforward hit. Thanks David!